# There are 2 ERD Designs, and one has a strange combination. I am told both are correct. why?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, erd

One of the designs seems clear: A REQUESTEDPRODUCT is picked from STOCK (which has many locations). The primary key is a composite key of 4 foreign keys.

The other design is more unclear. The "PICKING_LIST" is an intermediate table between REQUESTEDPRODUCT and PICKED_AMOUNT.
PICKING_LIST here has a PK that is matching with ReqId, through an FK?
Can this last option work?
If yes or not, why can or cannot it work?

[image: Design 1]
[image: Design 2]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change much.

The second design adds the constraint that all the items (with same reqid) in a picking list refer to the same employee. The relation between Employee and Picking-List is one-to-many. One employee could have many picking lists. I don't see why it wouldn't work. – [user993](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9)